# Copy record to another table when a field value changes

Tags: php, mysql

Consider 2 tables:

```
-- Table apples
id  |  randomstring  |  type TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0

-- Table pears
id  |  randomstring | is_complete TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
```

Much like PHP events, is it possible to detect that when the field  `pears.is_complete` is updated to a 1 from a 0, MySQL automatically copies the contents of `pears.randomstring` to `apples.randomstring` and sets the value of `apples.type` to 1?

If this is not possible in MySQL, can it be done in PHP where **a php file is called when the value of a field changes?**

Comment: Look up "triggers" in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your running MySQL 5.0.2 or greater then using a trigger might be your best bet.  Just create an update trigger that would run when the is_complete value changes to a 1.

Trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `{database name}`.`{name of trigger}` 
  AFTER UPDATE ON `{database name}`.`pears`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF(NEW.is_complete = 1) THEN
    # Add your random string to the apple table code
    INSERT INTO `{database name}`.`apples` (randomstring, type)
    VALUES (NEW.randomstring, 1);
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER;
```